# Azure Functions trigger for when a new key version is created or expired Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to see if it is possible to have a trigger setup within Azure Functions that will fire off when Key Vault has a new version of a key created. It doesn't seem that there is a supported trigger at the moment, but wanted to see if someone else has had this type of idea and might have some solution in mind.

The use case I had in mind was for a on premise cache of keys and we wanted to setup an easy way to update/refresh the cache when key versions are created or expired so the data stays up to date.

Also, if this is a stupid idea, I'm open to suggestions of alternative ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Functions currently does not have support for Key Vault triggers. However, it seems that Key Vault has ability to send activity logs to Event Hub and there is support for Event Hub triggers in Azure Functions. Not sure if this would work for your use-case and I am not familiar with the SIEM pipeline, but here are some references that may help:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/security-azure-log-integration-keyvault-eventhub
2. https://mitra.computa.asia/articles/msdn-integrate-azure-logs-streamed-event-hubs-siem

Comment: nice, I tried and it is working fine. Only `AuditEvent` are relevant. There is `SecretSet` operationName. So pushing auditlogs to eventhub definitely works. Just need to filter event based on operationname. dont know if there is a way of filtering these events using eventgrid ?

Comment: @Thomas, For simple solution and less cost, the pushing AuditLogs to the event-driven storage and using EventGridTrigger function with an input blob binding can help to filter on the operationName, properties.id, callerIpAddress, etc. and generate an event for EventGrid custom topic and/or SignalR Service. In the case of the streaming path, the ASA job can be useful for analyzing logs across more applications, etc. Btw. it will be nice pushing some events (for instance: create secret, delete secret, update secrets, etc.) from this entity (Key Vault) direct to the Event Grid model.

Comment: @RomanKiss, yeah at the end it is always a matter of cost ;-)